# Using personal account (live.com) to get an access token for my app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I am having trouble getting an access token using the **password** grant auth end point.

I created an app registration in my Azure account which is tied to my personal live.com Microsoft account.

In the application settings I've set the **supported account types** to **AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount** *(Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox))*

When I attempt to to authorize via my personal account's username/password using the [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) end point using grant_type=password I get the following error:

*AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the xxx-xxx directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.*

I am not sure how this is possible as I am obviously the only member of my Azure AD.

[image]

The app, **Todo Inventory** is listed under the applications in the user profile as shown below:

[image]

Note that I am successfully able to get an access token using the auth code flow described in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

But I want to use the password grant instead but nothing I tried seem to be working.

Am I missing something here..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft identity platform doesn't support resource owner password flow for personal accounts. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

> The Microsoft identity platform endpoint only supports ROPC for Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. This means that you must use a tenant-specific endpoint ([https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenantId_or_Name%7D)) or the organizations endpoint.